# Doctrine is updating related entity together with the target entiity

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony1

My problem is the follow:
I have the entity A with a fk(join columns) from entity B, and every time I create or update an entity A updates values in my B entity. Is normal that behavior?

Comment: could please post the entity association?

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behavior in some contexts, all depends on how you set the association between them.

If you only want to update an specific entity without alter any other, you could do:

```
$em->flush($entityA);
```

Also, you could considere use the cascate specification in order to lets doctrine how do you want yo manage your associations:

```
cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"}
```